# Installation error on iPadOS 17 and iOS 17: "Failed to verify code signature"

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, ipados

I have all my Apple devices up-to-date (macOS Sonoma 14.0, iPadOS 17.0.2, iOS 17.0.2, watchOS 10.0.1, Xcode 15.0).  I have an app I am working on, Date-O-Rama, and until a few days ago, Xcode installed it on my iPad and iPhone.  Now I am getting cryptic errors when I try to install and run a new build of Date-O-Rama on either device:

Error message for the iPad:

> לא ניתן להתקין את ״Date-O-Rama״
> [Translation from the Hebrew:
> Could not install “Date-O-Rama”.]
> Failed to verify code signature
> of
> /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.cRw8yc/extracted/Payload/Date-O-Rama.app
> : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.) Verify that the
> Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device.
> Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device
> Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.

Error message for the iPhone:

> Failed to install the app on the device.

I have tried making sure the developer app certificate is installed on my iPhone and iPad.  The devices claim the certificate is not trusted and do not let me make them trusted.

For comparison:  I can install and run Date-O-Rama without problems on my MacBook Pro (in Catalyst).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 16):

Annoyingly Ade's solution didn't work for me, but what did work was deleting the app from my phone. Then when I ran it again, it installed and worked fine.

Comment: This works for me.  Thanks!

Comment: worked, thanks!

Comment: While this works, deleting the app can be cumbersome. Check my solution below for an alternative solution not requiring app deletion

Answer (score 5):

I have just updated my phone to iOS 17.0.2 and encountered this as well, what fixed it for me was:

- Go to Manage Run Destinations
- Unpair device
- Unplug the device then quit Xcode
- Plug the device back in
- Launch Xcode
- Tap trust on the popup, then run again

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Ade's solution didn't work for me. Fiona's solution works, but I don't like having to delete the app since it deletes all its data and can take some time to reconfigure.

I've just found out another solution that worked for me: if you already have a version of your app on the App Store or on TestFlight, download it from there (it will overwrite your current dev app). Then, when you run from Xcode, it should start working again normally! And you've kept all the app data :)

Not a solution for everyone since it requires having your app already released or on TestFlight, but it can be useful for those working on updates!

Comment: Great solution. Deleting and re-installing the app requires too much re-configuration for me

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the build folder fixed this problem for me. For context, I had an earlier error because my login had expired. This login failure was retained in the cache, and clearing the cache solved the problem installing the app on the test device.